# Mongodb Return results and its inverse

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to return results that match query and those that do not in one query?

Say I have the following data:

```
{
    name: 'name1',
    age: 19
},
{
    name: 'name2',
    age: 20
},
{
    name: 'name3',
    age: 18
},
{
    name: 'name4',
    age: 22
},
{
    name: 'name5',
    age: 25
}
```

I would like to have a query that returns results that fit the filtering and those that dont.

```
db.names.aggregate([
    { $match: { age: { $gt: 20 } } }
]);
```

Something like this:

```
db.names.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                {
                    $gt: 20,
                    $project: '$gt20'
                },
                {
                    $lte: 20,
                    $project: 'NOT$gt20'
                },
            ]
        }
    }
]);
```

The results should be something like this.

```
{
    $gt20: [
        {
            name: 'name4',
            age: 22
        },
        {
            name: 'name5',
            age: 25
        }
    ],
    NOT$gt20: [
        {
            name: 'name1',
            age: 19
        },
        {
            name: 'name2',
            age: 20
        },
        {
            name: 'name3',
            age: 18
        }
    ]
}
```

I was wondering whether it can bo done in one query as opposed to two queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) to split your pipeline into 2 different pipelines, and use [$not](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) to negate your query condition, I would avoid customizing it myself with `$lte` as `not $gt` !==  `$lte` due to the possibility of missing fields for example.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      "gt20": [
        {
          $match: {
            age: {
              $gt: 20
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "NOTgt20": [
        {
          $match: {
            age: {
              $not: {
                $gt: 20
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ztTuN3duXVW)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$facet` stage to separate the result, `$match` stage to match your condition,

```
db.names.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      gt20: [
        { $match: { age: { $gt: 20 } } }
      ],
      NOTgt20: [
        { $match: { age: { $lte: 20 } } }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GjYdpa-f08w)